# Will a switch and router on different subnet masks have problems?

Tags: home-networking

I am using an old Cisco Router as a switch on my network to hardwire my basement.  Only wired connections will be used in the basement for this switch.  I am following the directions from here: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/174419/how-to-reuse-your-old-wi-fi-router-as-a-network-switch/ All is good, except when it comes to using the same subnet mask on the switch as on the router, which is what the directions say to do.  The router is set to get internet address dynamically from ISP, and the subnet mask choice is greyed out.  It is set to 255.255.248.0, and that is what comes up when I check the connection.  The switch does not have a choice for 255.255.248.0.  Therefore I cannot choose the same subnet mask and have the router get internet address dynamically.
However, on initial testing the switch seems to work.

What problems will arise if I have a different subnet for my router and switch?
If there will be problems, what options do I have for a different configuration?

Thanks,
MA

Answer (score 0):

When acting as a pure switch, the IP configuration is only needed for management. In other words, it is only used when accessing the device's admin panel, but has no effect on packets forwarded (switched) through it.

However, your LAN netmask has absolutely nothing to do with your WAN configuration. (Remember that a router is in two networks at once, and they can have different parameters.) So if you're using the switch in your LAN, you *don't need* to use 255.255.240.0 "just because that's what the ISP uses". You need to use *what your LAN uses.*